# Calling a variable from parent MY_Controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, global-variables, codeigniter-3

I want to make my logo global so that I can access it anywhere in my website. For that I am declaring `$logo` in a custom parent controller MY_Authorization and every class is extended by this custom controller.

but when i call the $logo variable in my view a php error occurs that undefined variable: $logo

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Authorization extends CI_Controller {
var $logoCont='logo';
    function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('session');
    $CI->load->helper('url');
    if ( !$this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
    { 
        redirect('login');
    }
  }
}
```

In my view i am calling logo like this

```
  <img src="<?php echo base_url().sprintf("uploads/%s", $logoCont)?>"alt="logo">
```

Comment: Create a custom helper file ,write this function in that file and autoload this custom file in autoload.php which is placed in config folder of CI directory

Comment: `$this->logoCont` could do a trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom helper file and placed in helper folder

1. Navigate to *application/helper*
2. List item
3. Create a new custom file

**example : my_custom_helper.php**

```
function logo(){
   $ci = & get_instance();
   $result = $ci->db->query("you custom query here");
   //fetch the logo from database and store in the variable  and return this variable 
   return $result;
}
```

4. autoload this helper in autoload.php file at *(application/config/autoload.php)*
5. find the variable `$autoload['helper'] = array();`
6. add your custom helper there like `$autoload['helper'] = array('my_custom_helper.php);`
7. Now the `logo()` function is global and it will available everywhere in controller/model/view ,and whenever change made in helper function it will be affect the application where `logo()` function is used.

Comment: I want to access it using Controller because the logo is dynamic and it is being called from the database. the path is called from database, it is saved in $logo variable and then this variable is called in a view

Comment: this can also be achieved with helper file

Comment: I have edited my post plz review the change to get the value of logo from the database

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not being passed on to the view.

```php
if ( !$this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
{ 
    ---added this---
    $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
    // OR $this->session->set_flashdata($data); $data is of type array
    ----------------
    redirect('login');
}
```

Now your data is set in the session (and will be removed after the next request), you can access this data in the view by using $this->session->flashdata('item').

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Hope this helps.